# Adding unique items to a ListView in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am processing a csv file and would like to summarise the information into a list view.
The idea behind this is to have a list with four columns:

- sum up the customer code
- sum up the order qty
- sum up the delivery qty
- and display the percentage being delivered

Issue:
At the moment my code is adding all the entries (i understand this as I haven't added any checks yet to sum them before adding them to the list)

My question is, how do I sum this information and add 1 row with the summary instead of the individual lines?

```
lineDetail = New Line
                'populate line details
                lineDetail.OriginalOrderLine = originalOrderLine
                lineDetail.ProductCode = productCode
                lineDetail.OrderQuantity = orderQty
                lineDetail.SentQuantity = sentQty
                lineDetail.RevisedOrderQuantity = orderQty
                lineDetail.CustomerWSP = customerWSP
                lineDetail.NatProductCode = natProducCode
                lineDetail.CustProductCode = custProductCode
                lineDetail.customerRSP = customerRSP
                headerDetail.Lines.Add(lineDetail)

                'Add list to summary List
                Dim newDeliverable As Integer = ((sentQty / orderQty) * 100%)
                Dim strOrderWty As String = orderQty
                ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {customerCode, strOrderWty, sentQty, newDeliverable & " %"}))
```

[image]

Comment: What if sentQty is 5 and orderOty is 15. How can that produce an Integer? I think division always produces a Double.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Why would you want the sum of customer code? Wouldn't that be a meaningless number?

Comment: Hi Mary thanks for that. you are write i do not want to sum the customer code. I meant to say to count them.
I have figured out a better way to do this. I will post the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used System.Linq
and summed the informatiuon before adding to the list using something like this:

SummaryList = New List(Of SummaryLines)

```
    For Each row In Headers
        SummaryList.Add(New SummaryLines(row.CustomerCode,
                        row.Lines.Sum(Function(t) t.OriginalOrderLine),
                        row.Lines.Sum(Function(t) t.RevisedOrderQuantity)))
    Next
```

The final result came out like this:
[image]